# Rails nested attribute - wrong last output

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, nested-attributes

I have a Article object with nested attributes Property.
Now I want to print it at the front in show.html.erb

I can print all attributes, but at the I get at the end an ouput that looks like a map with all objects inside. What am I doing wrong?

**show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <%= @article.properties.each do |property| %>
      <li>
      <b><%= property.name %></b> <%= property.value %>
      </li>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :properties
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :properties 
end
```

**and the wrong html output in the browser**

```
Property_6588 Value_6588
Property_9390 Value_9390
Property_15367 Value_15367
Property_19710 Value_19710
[#<Property id: 6588, name: "Property_6588", value: "Value_6588", article_id: 4766, created_at: "2012-04-12 13:33:23", updated_at: "2012-04-12 13:33:23">, #<Property id: 9390, name: "Property_9390", value: "Value_9390", article_id: 4766, created_at: "2012-04-12 13:33:29", updated_at: "2012-04-12 13:33:29">, #<Property id: 15367, name: "Property_15367", value: "Value_15367", article_id: 4766, created_at: "2012-04-12 13:33:41", updated_at: "2012-04-12 13:33:41">, #<Property id: 19710, name: "Property_19710", value: "Value_19710", article_id: 4766, created_at: "2012-04-12 13:33:50", updated_at: "2012-04-12 13:33:50">]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<%= @article.properties.each do |property| %>
```

to

```
<% @article.properties.each do |property| %>
```

The `=` sign renders the following statement, in this case the collection you're iterating through.